# I Need to Check the Object before parsing response into Mapping class by javax.xml,

Tags: java, xml-parsing, objectmapper

Some times I am getting planName as ('NewYork', 'China') then, I don't want to parse that value instead of those values i want to persist empty string in Database. Below is my parse class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Plan{

    @XmlElement(name = "branch", required = true)
    protected String branch;

    @XmlElement(name = "planName",required = true)
    protected String planName;

    @XmlElement(name = "subPlan", required = true)
    protected String subPlan;

     //Getters and Setters..
 }
```

I tried, after parsing, I can able to check the field value by String comparison. But I am facing this issue as like above for many fields. So I need to check each field before parsing it.